# Checking opcode values

Tags: c#

What troubles me are the empty `/**/` brackets. Is there a cleaner way of handling this logic?

```
if (opcode == OP_0) { /* continue */}
    else if (opcode == OP_1NEGATE) { /* continue */}
    else if (opcode >= OP_1 && opcode <= OP_16) { /* continue */}
    else { throw new Exception("decodeFromOpN called on non OP_N opcode"); }
```

Comment: I see that most answers copy the indentation from the question.  I would expect the `else if` chain to align with the initial `if`.  When I see an indented `else` I tend to start looking for an `if` at the same level.  In general, indent only once within a control structure, but keep the control structure *keywords* at the level where it starts.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What you could use is a function that returns whether an opcode is valid.

```
private boolean isOpCode(Object opCode){
    return opcode == OP_0 || opcode == OP_1NEGATE || (opcode >= OP_1 && opcode <= OP_16);
}
```

Then in your code you posted, call the function, and throw an exception if it returns false.

```
if(!isOpCode(opCode)){
    throw new OpCodeInvalidException("decodeFromOpN called on non OP_N opcode");
}
```

Replace `Object` with whatever the opcodes are.

And make a new class that extends from `Exception`. It's generally bad practice to throw `Exception`.

Comment: The conditional OR operator (`||`) should be used instead of the bit-wise logical OR operator (`|`). Semantically it is closer to the meaning, and it can be short-circuited to avoid having to evaluate the entire expression.

Comment: I see a lot of redundancy here. Why check through each opcode to see if such one exists, only to cycle through again looking for the action it performs? Switching just seems much simpler.

Comment: @Liamdev631, I agree with your idea, to make a switch statement for all of the opcodes, then go from there. **However**, he asked for a cleaner way of handling the logic. Also, if `OP_???` are integers, then calling `isOpCode` runs relatively quickly.

Answer (score 13):

The `else` branch can only be executed if all the other conditions are false:

```
if (opcode != OP_0
  && opcode != OP_1NEGATE
  && (opcode < OP_1 || opcode > OP_16))
{
    throw ...;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I don't like the empty blocks after the `if` statements.  Its very confusing, and clutters up your code.

I also don't like that you are throwing a general `Exception`.  Create one and throw that exception instead.

```
public class InvalidOpCodeException : Exception
{
    private int OpCode { get; private set; }

    public InvalidOpCodeException(int opCode)
        : base(string.Format("OpCode supplied is invalid {0}.", opCode)
    {
        OpCode = opCode;
    }

}
```

I would change it to just look for the error case

```
if (opcode != OP_0
    && opcode != OP_1NEGATE
    && (opcode < OP_1 || opcode > OP_16))
{
     throw new InvalidOpCodeException(opcode);
}

// Rest of the code here
```

Answer (score 10):

It might be more efficient to use a switch statement, then throw the exception if the opcode does not have a statement.

```
switch (opcode)
{
    case OP_0: { /* do stuffs */}
    case OP_1NEGATE: { /* do other stuffs */}
    ....
    default: { throw new Exception("a no no"); }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to assume that `OP_0`...`OP_16` are contiguous and that `OP_0` is the smallest possible value. In that case, it's trivial to collapse the conditions together:

```
if (opcode > OP_16 && opcode != OP_1NEGATE)
   throw new Exception("decodeFromOpN called on non OP_N opcode");
```

If, however, `OP_0` may not be contiguous with `OP_1` or values less than OP_0 are possible, that could fail.

Answer (score 6):

If you separated the three cases because the opcode values/ranges mean different things, and you chose the same action (accept/skip) for different reasons, I think your style is fine.  A comment describing the meaning of each case is useful for the next person to read the code:

```
if (opcode == OP_0) { /* OP_0 (zero) is a no-op, ok */}
    else if (opcode == OP_1NEGATE) { /* flip register value */}
    else if (opcode >= OP_1 && opcode <= OP_16) { /* known allocated opcodes */}
    else { throw new Exception("decodeFromOpN called on non OP_N opcode"); }
```

This way it's clearer that the cases had different meanings when you wrote it.  As the code evolves, future maintainers can add/break out/consolidate cases as their meaning changes, and/or add debugging information or change actions for the individual cases if necessary.

However, per others' answers, if the cases have roughly the same meaning in the local context of this code, consolidating the conditions makes sense.

Comment: This sort of design may be particularly good if the same sequence of tests is done in several methods, and each case has a semantic meaning [possibly explicit no-op].  For example, if the code selects a sequence of `if` statements based upon an operating mode, a command to "switch to XXX mode (if not already in that mode)" could be handled as a no-op in the XXX mode `if`-block, but perform an action for the `if` blocks associated with other modes.